# assert_route failing with good route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, functional-testing, rails-routing

I'm writing a functional test but it fails with the following error:

```
1) Failure:
test: routing should route GET /categories/1/inventory_items/2/edit to/from {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"inventory_items", :category_id=>"1", :id=>"2"}. (InventoryItemsControllerTest)
    []:
No route matches "/categories/1/inventory_items/2/edit"
```

with route:

```
resources :categories, :constraints => lambda { |request| Category.exists?(request.params['category_id']) } do
  resources :inventory_items
end
```

and my rake routes:

```
      category_inventory_items GET    /categories/:category_id/inventory_items(.:format)          inventory_items#index
                               POST   /categories/:category_id/inventory_items(.:format)          inventory_items#create
   new_category_inventory_item GET    /categories/:category_id/inventory_items/new(.:format)      inventory_items#new
  edit_category_inventory_item GET    /categories/:category_id/inventory_items/:id/edit(.:format) inventory_items#edit
       category_inventory_item GET    /categories/:category_id/inventory_items/:id(.:format)      inventory_items#show
                               PUT    /categories/:category_id/inventory_items/:id(.:format)      inventory_items#update
                               DELETE /categories/:category_id/inventory_items/:id(.:format)      inventory_items#destroy
```

I tried creating a `Category` object with `:id` of 1, but it still fails. I did a `puts` in my route and the `params` hash is `{}`! I'm using shoulda matcher like so:

```
should route(:get, "/categories/1/inventory_items/2").to(:action => "show", :controller => "inventory_items", :category_id => 1, :id => 2)
```

and when I do a `puts` inside the matcher, the `params` is correctly filled:

```
{:action=>"show", :controller=>"inventory_items", :category_id=>"1", :id=>"2"}
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I figured it out: I needed to mock Category#exists? to return true: Category.stubs(:exists?).returns(true).